# __sleep() and superclass properties

Tags: php, oop, serialization, sleep

Given two classes:

```
class A
{
   private $prop1;
}
class B extends A
{
   private $prop2;
   public function __sleep()
   {
      return array('prop1','prop2');
   }
}
```

That will only serialize the value of `prop2` as it's a direct property of class B.

How can I get it to output the inherited `prop1` from superclass A?

**EDIT:**
Not defining the __sleep() will show the `private` properties in the serialized string without setting them to `protected`. They look something like `�A�prop1`, only I cannot get what the � is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Explicitly call the parent class's function and append the result:

```
class A
{
   private $prop1;
   public function __sleep()
   {
      return array('prop1');
   }
}

class B extends A
{
   private $prop2;

   public function __sleep()
   {
      $arr = parent::__sleep();
      array_push( $arr, 'prop2' );
      return $arr;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Francisc Any time you need to modify a parent class's return in a child, get it from the parent.

Comment: Yup, the only thing that wound me up was that if I did not define a __sleep() function, I would get the private properties in the resulting string with values in the form of `�A�prop1`. If I defined the __sleep() function those properties would be NULL.

Comment: Where `�A�` was the superclass name.

Comment: @Francisc you can use this to return all variables of the object, even the private ones from its superclass: `return array_keys((array)$this );`

Answer (score 2):

Private properties are not visible to child objects. You will need to change the visibility of `$prop1` to `protected` so `B` can access it:

```
protected $prop1;
```

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.

Comment: They _are_ inherited. They just are not visible to the derived code.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Thank you. The answer has been updated.

Comment: If I do not define a _sleep() function in B serialization works as it is supposed to.

Comment: Also, I am not trying to access the private property directly, it was a simplified example, I am instead calling a method from the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

A private member is not visible by any code in child classes. You will need [`protected`](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: Yes, it is. It's just not visible to the derived code.

Comment: @Tomalak +`. I've edited the wording to make it better.

Comment: No I don't. Look at the edit.