# magic function __sleep cannot return private properties

Tags: php, magic-methods

I know that there is a similar thread but I have tried what they suggested and it didn't work.

in php when an object is serialized there is an option do define in that class the magic function `__sleep` which is supposed to return an array with the values of all the object properties that would be serialized. But in php.net it is written that if we define the `__sleep` method for a object of a class that extends from another class then we cant write in the array values that represent private properties from the parent class. the thing is that they suggested a solution for this kind of situation, and I didn't really understood what they were trying to insinuate.

Here is what is written:

> Note:
>   It is not possible for __sleep() to return names of private properties in parent classes. Doing this will result in an E_NOTICE level error. Instead you may use the Serializable interface.

Here is the link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Also, in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626227/sleep-and-superclass-properties) they suggested something that I tried and it didn't work and sent me:

> Notice: serialize(): "name" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\questions\sleep_private_father.php on line 43

Here is the script:

```
<?php

class a
{
    private $name ;
    private $age ;

    function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        $this->name = $name ;
        $this->age = $age ;
    }

    function __sleep()
    {
        $vec = array("name") ;
        return $vec ;
    }
}

class b extends a
{
    private $last_name ;

    function __construct($name, $age ,$last_name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $age) ;
        $this->last_name = $last_name ;
    }

    function __sleep()
    {
        $array = parent::__sleep() ;

        array_push( $array, 'last_name' );
        return $array ;
    }

}

$ob = new b("michal" , 26 , "smith") ;
var_dump($ob) ;
$ob_ser = serialize($ob) ;
var_dump(unserialize($ob_ser)) ;

?>
```

I'm also curious of the way that php.net suggested to use the serializble interface.

Comment: Implementing [Serializable](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) is a much better way to go.

Comment: can you look at the answer that  I posted a few minutes ago. I implemented the serializable, is it right how I did it?

Comment: The `get_class` checks are a bit of a code smell IMO; I'd be tempted to do something like this: http://codepad.org/JuPMm17T

Comment: hmm clever. thanks. I also added another solution

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626227/sleep-and-superclass-properties

Answer (score 1):

Private operator mean that the attribute or function can be used only in class and cant be extends. If you want implement mechanism to store attribute in child class you should try something like:

```
  class foo{
     protected $test = 'a';
     public function __sleep() {
           return array('test');
     }
  }
  class bar extends foo{

     public function getTest(){
          return $this->test;
  }

}   

 $bar = new bar();
 $serialized = serialize($bar);
 $object = unserialize($serialized);
 echo $object->getTest();
```

OR

```
 class foo{
     protected $test = 'a';
 }
 class bar extends foo{

     public function __sleep() {
        return array('test');
    }

    public function getTest(){
        return $this->test;
    }

 }

 $bar = new bar();
 $serialized = serialize($bar);
 $object = unserialize($serialized);
 echo $object->getTest();
```

Last way i used operator protected instead private

Comment: but I didn't understood how can I use the __sleep method on a object with private properties in the parent class. in php.net they suggest to use the serialize interface, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can do small hack if you name parent property like this `"\0". parent::class. "\0parentProperty"`

```php
<?php
namespace bed {
class A {
    private $id=5;
    protected $b;
    public $c;
    public function __sleep()
    {
        return ['id'];
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public function __sleep(){
        return  parent::__sleep();
    }
}

class D extends A{
    public function __sleep(){
        return ["\0bed\A\0id"];
    }
}

class CoolD extends A {
    private $d;
    protected $e;
    public $f;

    public function __sleep(){
        $allProperties = [];
        $reflection  = new \ReflectionClass($this);
        do{
            foreach ($reflection->getProperties() as $prop) {
                $allProperties[($prop->isPrivate()
                    ? "\0" . $prop->getDeclaringClass()->getName() . "\0" . $prop->getName()
                    : $prop->getName())] = true;
            }
        }while($reflection = $reflection->getParentClass());
        return array_keys($allProperties);
    }
}

class C extends A{
}

// var_dump(serialize(new C)); - not working
// var_dump(serialize(new B)); - not working
var_dump(serialize(new D));
var_dump(serialize(new CoolD));
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ZpPhR

Answer (score 0):

Note from your link (php.net) mean that:

```
Note:
It is not possible for __sleep() to return names of private properties 
in parent classes. Doing this will result in an E_NOTICE level error. 
Instead you may use the Serializable interface.
```

If you will try to reutrn in __sleep method array with private property (doesnt matter if it is parent or child class) always you get notice error. Is possible to avoid this notice and get name of private property using serializable interface.

If your class implements serializable interface you should`nt use __sleep method beacuse Classes that implement this interface no longer support __sleep() and __wakeup() methods. :

```
 Serializable {
    /* Methods */
    abstract public string serialize ( void )
    abstract public void unserialize ( string $serialized )
 }
```

serialize will be call when your object will go to serialize status (object -> string) and unserialize when your object will go to unserialize (string -> object). You cant read|write private properties parent class in child class (when you try to get this property from method in child class). for example:

```
  class foo implements Serializable{
     private $id;
     public function serialize() {
        return serialize('hello world');
     }
     public function unserialize($serialized) {
        $this->id = unserialize($serialized);
     }
     public function get_id_from_foo(){
        return $this->id;
     }
 }

 class bar extends foo{
     public function get_id_from_bar(){
         return $this->id;
     }
 }

 $bar = new bar();
 $serializedBar = serialize($bar);
 $unserializedBar = unserialize($serializedBar);
 echo $unserializedBar->get_id_from_bar();

 //RESULT : Undefined property: bar::$id
```

But if you change in foo class private $id to protected $id you get 'hello world'.

In other case when you try to get private property from method extendend from parent for example:

```
class foo implements Serializable{
    private $id;
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize('hello world');
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        $this->id = unserialize($serialized);
    }
    public function get_foo_id_from_parent(){
        return $this->id;
    }
 }

 class bar extends foo{
     public function set_id(){
         $this->id = 'something else';
     }
    public function get_foo_id_from_bar(){
        return $this->id;
    }
 }

$bar = new bar();
$bar->set_id();
$serializedBar = serialize($bar);
$unserializedBar = unserialize($serializedBar);
echo $unserializedBar->get_foo_id_from_parent();
//RESULT 'hello world'; But this property is from parent!!
```

Answer (score 0):

ok you all gave me ideas to solve my exact problem, which is getting a result as if I could have defined in a sleep method of an object from an extended class a private property from the parent class. here is my solution:

```
<?php 
class foo implements Serializable
{
    private $id;
    private $name ;

    public function serialize() 
    {
        $array_properties_to_serialize = array('id' => $this->id) ;

        // this if will indicate if an object from the foo class invoked the method 
        //or an object from the extend class (bar) 

        if (get_class($this) == "foo") 
        {  
            // foo object invoked the method , so we will want to serialize only the $id property 

           return serialize($array_properties_to_serialize);
        }

        elseif (get_class($this) == "bar")
        {
            // bar object invoked the method so we will want to add to the  array of properties
             //the $last_name property from the bar class, and then serialize it 
            return $array_properties_to_serialize ;
       }
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) 
    {
         $array_properties_unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
         $this->id = $array_properties_unserialized['id'] ;

         if (get_class($this) == "bar")
         {
            // bar object invoked the method so we will send to the overriding method the $array_properties_unserialized
            // so it could set the properties of the extended object accordingly.
            return $array_properties_unserialized ;
         }
    }

    public function __construct($id,$name)
    {
        $this->name = $name ;
        $this->id = $id ;
    }
 }

 class bar extends foo
 {
    private $last_name ;

    public function serialize()
    {
        $array_properties_to_serialize = parent::serialize() ;
        $array_properties_to_serialize["last_name"] = $this->last_name ;  

        return serialize($array_properties_to_serialize);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
     {
        $array_properties_unserialized = parent::unserialize($serialized) ;
        $this->last_name = $array_properties_unserialized['last_name']; ;
    }

    public function __construct($id, $name , $last_name)
    {
        parent::__construct($id, $name) ;
        $this->last_name = $last_name ;
    }


 }

 echo "bar object: <br>" ;
$bar = new bar(12 , "tom" , "smith");
var_dump($bar) ;
$ob_ser = serialize($bar) ;
$ob_unser = unserialize($ob_ser) ;
echo "unserialized bar object  (didnt include the \$name property): <br>" ;
var_dump($ob_unser) ;

$foo = new foo(11 ,  "frank") ;
echo "foo object: <br>" ;
var_dump($foo) ;
$ob_ser = serialize($foo) ;
$ob_unser = unserialize($ob_ser) ;
echo "unserialized foo object (didnt include the \$name property): <br>" ;
var_dump($ob_unser) ;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

```
 <?php 
    class foo 
    {
        private $id;
        private $name ;

        public function serialize() 
        {
            $array_properties_to_serialize = array('id' => $this->id) ;           
               return serialize($array_properties_to_serialize);

        }

        // will be called only on a foo object because it doesnt implements serializable
        // when serialize a bar object it will only invoke the serialize method in the bar class
        public function __sleep()
        {
            return array('id') ;
        }


        public function getID()
        {
            return $this->id ;

        }

        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id ;
        }

        public function unserialize($serialized) 
        {
             $array_properties_unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
             $this->id = $array_properties_unserialized['id'] ;


        }

        public function __construct($id,$name)
        {
            $this->name = $name ;
            $this->id = $id ;
        }
     }

     class bar extends foo implements Serializable
     {
        private $last_name ;

        public function serialize()
        {
            $array_properties_to_serialize['id'] = $this->getID() ;
            $array_properties_to_serialize["last_name"] = $this->last_name ;  

            return serialize($array_properties_to_serialize);
        }

        public function unserialize($serialized)
         {
            $array_properties_unserialized = unserialize($serialized) ;
            $this->last_name = $array_properties_unserialized['last_name']; 
            $this->setId($array_properties_unserialized['id']) ;
        }

        public function __construct($id, $name , $last_name)
        {
            parent::__construct($id, $name) ;
            $this->last_name = $last_name ;
        }


     }

     echo "bar object: <br>" ;
    $bar = new bar(12 , "tom" , "smith");
    var_dump($bar) ;
    $ob_ser = serialize($bar) ;
    $ob_unser = unserialize($ob_ser) ;
    echo "unserialized bar object  (didnt include the \$name property): <br>" ;
    var_dump($ob_unser) ;

    $foo = new foo(11 ,  "john") ;
    echo "foo object: <br>" ;
    var_dump($foo) ;
    $ob_ser = serialize($foo) ;
    $ob_unser = unserialize($ob_ser) ;
    echo "unserialized foo object (didnt include the \$name property): <br>" ;
    var_dump($ob_unser) ;

    ?>
```